# Background images over hidden text bad for accessibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I need to display images of text instead of actual text for my menu.

Ive put a span within each menu link. These spans have a set hight and width, are set to display block, the text is minus indented to be hidden, and the background image is set to the image I want to use.

```
<li>
  <a href="site.com/page1">
    <span id="menu1"> 
      Link Text
    </span>
  </a> 
</li>
```

This is working fine cross browser. It also works fine when I enlarge and shrink the page. Are there any accessibility issues that aren't obvious eg for screen readers?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Screen readers**: it'll be fine with their users (blind and some partially sighted people) because text is off viewport but not hidden with `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` so it's still read.

**[High contrast mode](http://webaim.org/blog/high-contrast/)**: on Windows, this mode hides background images and uses custom colors to display content. CSS are still activated so text is visually hidden but the background image is gone: your menu is gone for many partially sighted users.

Images not loaded for one reason or another, by choice or not: same problem as with High Contrast mode as long as CSS are still active.

EDIT: many techniques are described plus pro and cons explained by Chris Coyer here: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/.
Though the most accessible one is *don't use background images when what you really want to use are HTML images with alt* :)

Comment: +1 nothing wrong with `<a href="/page1"><img src="foo.png" alt="Link Text" /></a>` and I think most of the SEO lore that insists that image replacement is better than plain old `alt` for SEO is specious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a css `background` will not be read by screen readers, moreover, it is bad for your SEO. What you could do is, use text there and then hide it either with:

```
text-indent, opacity:0
```

!!!I am not sure if it's considerd black hat SEO as you're just writing something thats already there!!!

Comment: Does it matter that the background image wont be read by screen readers? The real text is still there. My reason for using the text indent to hide it rather than just display none is that i heard screen readers may ignore hidden elements. thanks

Comment: though you had said you gotta use images of text instead of actual text, I assumed theres no "real" text.

<span class="span-with-bg"></span>  ->will not be seen by either google or screen readers.
<span class="span-with-bg">Menuitem</span>  -> will be seen.

how you play the css with the text between the spans will have no effect on screen readers.

Comment: Sorry, have updated my answer to make it clearer. So screen readers still see text thats displayed as none? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am almost sure display:none will be ignored by screen readers. You could try hiding it with z-index.

Comment: -1 `display: none` will prevent screenreaders from accessing the text.